# difficulties installing iHaskell

Tags: haskell, cabal, ihaskell

After much difficulty with `cabal install ihaskell` I read

> If you have trouble with this installation, please make sure to try the Github version first. IHaskell is in rapid development, so Hackage may not always be the most recent. In order to install from Github, pull from the repository, and then install with `./build.sh all`

This morning I upgraded to `ghc-7.8.4` and `cabal-1.22` and I am downloading iHaskell from the github repository using a simple `git clone`.

It is having difficulting locating several libraries.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHStransformers-compat-0.4.0.3-ghc7.8.4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSmtl-2.1.3.1-ghc7.8.4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHStagged-0.7.3-ghc7.8.4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHStext-1.2.0.4-ghc7.8.4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSvector-0.10.12.2-ghc7.8.4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSunordered-containers-0.2.5.1-ghc7.8.4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSsyb-0.4.4-ghc7.8.4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSmtl-2.1.3.1-ghc7.8.4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSdlist-0.7.1-ghc7.8.4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSattoparsec-0.12.1.3-ghc7.8.4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSscientific-0.3.3.7-ghc7.8.4
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lHShashable-1.2.3.1-ghc7.8.4
```

Unfortunately I can verify some of these are present.

```
me@ubuntu:~/Downloads/IHaskell$ cabal install mtl
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
mtl-2.2.1
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway
```

`ld` seems to be more of a C++ error than a Haskell error but I don't know how to deal.

- [usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<nameOfTheLibrary>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary)

Comment: does not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838712/cabal-reports-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lhsrandom-1-0-1-1-ghc7-8-3

Comment: Hurm.  You said `mtl-2.2.1` is installed but the library the linker is looking for is `mtl-2.1.3.1`.  I'd hazard to guess that _none_ of these are installed.

Answer (score 2):

After reading on StackOverflow and posting several issues on Github, I learned that my symlink to cabal was out of date.  For some reason it pointed to version 16 even after I downloaded and installed version 22.

[**semigroupoids** Issue #21](https://github.com/ekmett/semigroupoids/issues/21)

> Even after updating with `cabal install cabal-install` it still didn't recognize `sandbox init` and it fact `cabal -V` showed it was still version 16.
>
> Using `where cabal` I found the faulty cabal executable from my `ghc-7.6` installation and replaced it with a symlink.  In my case
>
> `sudo ln -s /home/jdm/.cabal/bin/cabal /usr/bin/cabal`
>
> So now I have cabal version 23, I opened a sandbox and **profunctors** (and **iHaskell**) install perfectly.  Case closed.